# pyclustering visualising xmeans when the matrix has more than three dimensions

Tags: python, plot, cluster-analysis, k-means, xmeans

I'm trying to cluster and visualise some data with xmeans from the pyclustering lib.
I copied the code directly from the [example](https://pyclustering.github.io/docs/0.9.0/html/dd/db4/classpyclustering_1_1cluster_1_1xmeans_1_1xmeans.html) in the documentation,

```
from pyclustering.cluster import cluster_visualizer
from pyclustering.cluster.xmeans import xmeans
from pyclustering.cluster.center_initializer import kmeans_plusplus_initializer
from pyclustering.utils import read_sample
from pyclustering.samples.definitions import SIMPLE_SAMPLES
sample = X # read_sample(SIMPLE_SAMPLES.SAMPLE_SIMPLE3)    
# Prepare initial centers - amount of initial centers defines amount of clusters from which X-Means will
# start analysis.
amount_initial_centers = 2
initial_centers = kmeans_plusplus_initializer(sample, amount_initial_centers).initialize()
# Create instance of X-Means algorithm. The algorithm will start analysis from 2 clusters, the maximum
# number of clusters that can be allocated is 20.
xmeans_instance = xmeans(sample, initial_centers, 20)
xmeans_instance.process()
# Extract clustering results: clusters and their centers
clusters = xmeans_instance.get_clusters()
centers = xmeans_instance.get_centers()
# Print total sum of metric errors
print("Total WCE:", xmeans_instance.get_total_wce())
# Visualize clustering results
visualizer = cluster_visualizer()
visualizer.append_clusters(clusters, sample)
visualizer.append_cluster(centers, None, marker='*', markersize=10)
visualizer.show()
```

The only difference is that I assigned to `sample` the value of my matrix X instead of loading a sample dataset.

When I try to visualise the clustering result I get this error:

```
Only objects with size dimension 1 (1D plot), 2 (2D plot) or 3 (3D plot) can be displayed. For multi-dimensional data use 'cluster_visualizer_multidim'.
```

My X matrix is generated in this way:

```
features = ["I", "Iu", other 7 column names]
data = df[features]
...
X = scaler.fit_transform(data)
```

**Is there a way to visualise the clusters and plotting only two/three features at a time?**

I can't find anything on the documentation.

I tried this:

```
visualizer.append_clusters(clusters, sample[:,[0,1]])
```

in order to visualise only the first two features and got this error

```
Only clusters with the same dimension of objects can be displayed on canvas.
```

EDIT:

I updated the code as suggested in the answer by annoviko but now I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-6fd7d2ce5fcd> in <module>
     20 visualizer.append_clusters(clusters, X)
     21 visualizer.append_cluster(centers, None, marker='*', markersize=10)
---> 22 visualizer.show(pair_filter=[[0, 1], [0, 2]])

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyclustering/cluster/__init__.py in show(self, pair_filter, **kwargs)
    224             raise ValueError("There is no non-empty clusters for visualization.")
    225 
--> 226         cluster_data = self.__clusters[0].data or self.__clusters[0].cluster
    227         dimension = len(cluster_data[0])
    228 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It is raised by visualizer.show(), and it happens even if I remove the pair_filter from within the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with the error that you got:

> Only objects with size dimension 1 (1D plot), 2 (2D plot) or 3 (3D plot) can be displayed. For multi-dimensional data use 'cluster_visualizer_multidim'.

You have to use `cluster_visualizer_multidim` as it was mentioned. There is a documentation (pyclustering 0.10.1) with an example: https://pyclustering.github.io/docs/0.10.1/html/dc/d6b/classpyclustering_1_1cluster_1_1cluster__visualizer__multidim.html

For example, if you have a data (`D > 3`) and you want to display `(x0, x1)` and `(x0, x2)` then you can display it in the following way:

```
visualizer = cluster_visualizer_multidim()
visualizer.append_clusters(clusters, sample_4d)
visualizer.show(pair_filter=[[0, 1], [0, 2]])
```

Where `pair_filter` specifies which features should be shown. In example above, it will show only `(x0, x1)` - `[0, 1]` and `(x0, x2)` - `[0, 2]`.

So, in your particular case where you have to display only first two features it should be:

```
visualizer = cluster_visualizer_multidim()
visualizer.append_clusters(clusters, sample)
visualizer.show(pair_filter=[[0, 1]])
```

I think I have to make error more readable and make a proposal to use another class in the first sentence. Let me know if it helps (if it is still relevant for you).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is still relevant. I thought I had to use the multidim only if I wanted to plot 3 or more features.

Comment: Do you knot what may be the reason for the raised exception?

Comment: @GerardoZinno, two different implementations. I have implemented `cluster_visualizer` as a some kind of natural visualization (1-3 dimensional data) and `cluster_visualizer_multidim` for all others cases. From user point of view the difference is in representation of 3-dimensional data (`cluster_visualizer` uses a single plot to display it `(x0, x1, x2)` and `cluster_visualizer_multidim` uses three plots `(x0, x1), (x0, x2) and (x1, x2)`). Would you prefer to see `cluster_visualizer` more generic? I can update it for the next release.

Comment: I meant the exception raised by the cluster_visualizer_multidim that I wrote in the edit :). I think it is fine that it uses three plots.

Comment: Yes, `cluster_visualizer_multidim` does not not support `numpy` yet, it is going to be supported in the next version `0.11.0`. Just convert your input data to list in the following way `visualizer.append_clusters(clusters, X.tolist())`.

Comment: Thanks, now the plotting doesn't raise the exception and it works. But do I need to pass `X.tolist()` to `kmeans_plusplus_initializer` and `xmeans` ? For now I pass to them X that's a numpy ndarray and no exceptions are raised

Comment: No, you do not need to do that for clustering algorithms, they should be able to work with `numpy` as well as with `list`. Just keep pass `numpy` data to algorithms :) .